# Get daily inventory using SQL Server even using while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, inventory

I have a Stocktaking inventory table that has an entry for once a month date and for all other dates that the inventory balance has can't be. The problem that I have is that I need to generate a report that shows daily balances for all days.

```
StoreNo   Date     ProductBarCode  ProducQty
--------------------------------------------
    61  2015-11-03  2300007115072   7
    61  2015-12-15  2300012213046   5
    21  2016-01-03  2300012712075   8
    61  2016-03-04  2300019012093   7
    61  2016-04-29  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-06-29  0065103700004   33
```

I want show daily bases inventory!

I do have two problems

1. how can I show every day's inventory with dates? If I add calendar table also, how can I get `2015-11-03` productBarcode and Qty until `2015-12-15` same productBarcode like this `(61  2015-11-03  2300007115072   7)`
2. if I choose `@date1 = 2015-11-05` and `@date2= 2015-11-08` still I want to show result like this during chosen dates where no product shown.

Result like this

```
StoreNo   Date     ProductBarCode  ProducQty
--------------------------------------------
    61  2015-11-05  2300007115072   7
    61  2015-11-06  2300007115072   7
    61  2015-11-07  2300007115072   7
    61  2015-11-08  2300007115072   7
```

I was facing this problem past one week! I'm not able to find any solution ..

I'm beginner at SQL trying to learn if there are any possibilities to solve this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried a calendar table here

```
Declare 
     @date1 date = '2015-12-01',
     @date2 date = '2015-12-05',
     @date_index date

create Table #calendar (Date date)

SET @date_index = @date1

WHILE @date_index <= @date2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #calendar
       SELECT @date_index

    SET @date_index = dateadd(day, 1, @date_index)

    IF @date_index > @date2
       BREAK
    ELSE
       CONTINUE
END
```

Comment: for all the dates between `12-12` and `01-03`,do you want to show `productqty` 5

Comment: @TheGameiswar above was sample table , i have 120 store no and productBarcode 1000 each of them as to show before date result ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using temp table for Inventory which you can replace it with your inventory table.

```
create table #inventory (StoreNo int ,[Date] date, ProductBarCode varchar(14),ProductQty int )

insert into #inventory

SELECT 61,  '2015-11-03',  '2300007115072',   7   UNION ALL
SELECT 61,  '2015-12-15',  '2300012213046',   5   UNION ALL
SELECT 21,  '2016-01-03',  '2300012712075',   8   UNION ALL
SELECT 61,  '2016-03-04',  '2300019012093',   7   UNION ALL
SELECT 61,  '2016-04-29',  '2017961746012',   100 UNION ALL
SELECT 61,  '2016-06-29',  '0065103700004',   33  


DECLARE @dt1 Datetime='2015-11-05'
DECLARE @dt2 Datetime='2015-11-08'

;WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [Dates]=@dt1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [dates] + 1 
         FROM   ctedaterange 
         WHERE  [dates] + 1<= @dt2) 
SELECT A.StoreNo,C.[dates],A.ProductBarCode,A.ProductQty
FROM   ctedaterange C
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #inventory I WHERE I.Date < C.DATES ORDER BY I.Date DESC
) A
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

It will work for other date ranges too. Just change the values of @dt1 and @dt2.

Comment: `StoreNo dates ProductBarCode ProductQty
916 2015-12-02 00:00:00.000 2300000314076 18
916 2015-12-03 00:00:00.000 2300000314076 18
61 2015-12-04 00:00:00.000 2300007115072 7
61 2015-12-05 00:00:00.000 2300007115072 7
61 2015-12-06 00:00:00.000 2300007115072 7`                       after 916 after 2015-12-03  its not show qty and 61 after 3rd only its show value because inventory taken on 3rd for 61 thats why its showing after that but i wanna show previous dates also 2nd and 3rd

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get what you are saying. Can you please give sample data and expected result that would help understanding it.

Comment: `StoreNo date             ProductBarCode    ProductQty
NULL 2015-12-01             NULL       NULL
NULL 2015-12-02        NULL           NULL 
NULL 2015-12-03        NULL               NULL
61         2015-12-04  2300007115072 7
61       2 015-12-04  2300012213046 5
61       2015-12-04  2300012712075 8`  I was getting result like this ! BUT i cant able to show NULL in those dates also

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully help

```
Declare @date1 date = '2015-12-01'
              ,@date2 date = '2015-12-05'
              ,@date_index date
create Table #calende  (Date date)
SET @date_index = @date1

WHILE @date_index<=@date2
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #calende
SELECT @date_index

SET @date_index = dateadd(day,1,@date_index)

IF @date_index>@date2
Break
ELSE
Continue
END

select (CASE WHEN I.[Date] IS NULL THEN 61
            ELSE
                I.[StoreNo]
        END) AS StoreNo ,
        C.[Date],
        (CASE WHEN I.[Date] IS NULL THEN 61
            ELSE
                I.[StoreNo]
        END) AS StoreNo ,
        (CASE WHEN I.[Date] IS NULL THEN 2300007115072
            ELSE
                I.[ProductBarCode]
        END) AS ProductBarCode ,
        (CASE WHEN I.[Date] IS NULL THEN 7
            ELSE
                I.[ProducQty]
        END) AS ProducQty ,      
from #calende C
    left join [YourTable] I on I.[Date] = C.[Date]

drop table #calende
```